# GroupBy and reduce an array of object in a pointfree style

Tags: javascript, reduce, ramda.js

I recently started using `Ramda` and trying to find a pointfree way to write a method to reduce an array of objects.

Here is the array of object :

```
const someObj = [
    {
        name: 'A',
        city: 1,
        other: {
            playtime: 30
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        city: 2,
        other: {
            playtime: 20
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'c',
        city: 1,
        other: {
            playtime: 20
        }
    }
];
```

What I am trying is to reduce the object using [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) in poinfree style like

```
{
    '1': {
        count: 2,
        avg_play_time: 20 + 30 / count
    },
    '2': {
        count: 1,
        avg_play_time: 20 / count
    }
}
```

I can do it using an array reduce method but not sure how can I write the same in ramda pointfree style. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: is `avg_play_time` string or it should be calculated?

Comment: it should be calculated based on the entries.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - agreed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to do something like this:

```
// An optic to extract the nested playtime value
// Coupled with a `lift` operation which allows it to be applied over a collection
// Effectively A -> B => A[] -> B[]
const playtimes = R.lift(R.path(['other', 'playtime']))

R.pipe(
  // Group the provided array by the city value
  R.groupBy(R.prop('city')),
  // Return a body specification which computes each property based on the 
  // provided function value.
  R.map(R.applySpec({
    count: R.length,
    average: R.pipe(playtimes, R.mean)
  }))
)(someObj)
```

Comment: Note that your `average` is already built into Ramda as [`R.mean`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mean).

Comment: Ah good call I was just searching for `average` in the docs. Synonyms...

Answer (score 2):

Ramda also has another function called [`R.reduceBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduceBy) which provides something inbetween `reduce` and `groupBy`, allowing you to fold up values with matching keys together.

So you can create a data type like the following that tallies up the values to averaged.

```
const Avg = (count, val) => ({ count, val })
Avg.of = val => Avg(1, val)
Avg.concat = (a, b) => Avg(a.count + b.count, a.val + b.val)
Avg.getAverage = ({ count, val }) => val / count
Avg.empty = Avg(0, 0)
```

Then combine them together using `R.reduceBy`.

```
const avgCities = R.reduceBy(
  (avg, a) => Avg.concat(avg, Avg.of(a.other.playtime)),
  Avg.empty,
  x => x.city
)
```

Then pull the average values out of the `Avg` into the shape of the final objects.

```
const buildAvg = R.applySpec({
  count: x => x.count,
  avg_play_time: Avg.getAverage
})
```

And finally pipe the two together, mapping `buildAvg` over the values in the object.

```
const fn = R.pipe(avgCities, R.map(buildAvg))
fn(someObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another suggestion using `reduceBy` with mapping an `applySpec` function on each property of the resulting object:

The idea is to transform `someObj` into this object using `getPlaytimeByCity`:

```
{ 1: [30, 20],
  2: [20]}
```

Then you can map the `stats` function on each property of that object:

```
stats({ 1: [30, 20], 2: [20]});
// { 1: {count: 2, avg_play_time: 25}, 
//   2: {count: 1, avg_play_time: 20}}
```

```js
const someObj = [
    { name: 'A',
      city: 1,
      other: { playtime: 30 }},
    { name: 'B',
      city: 2,
      other: { playtime: 20 }},
    { name: 'c',
      city: 1,
      other: { playtime: 20 }}
];

const city = prop('city');
const playtime = path(['other', 'playtime']);
const stats = applySpec({count: length, avg_play_time: mean});
const collectPlaytime = useWith(flip(append), [identity, playtime]);
const getPlaytimeByCity = reduceBy(collectPlaytime, [], city);

console.log(

  map(stats, getPlaytimeByCity(someObj))
  
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {prop, path, useWith, flip, append, identity, applySpec, length, mean, reduceBy, map} = R;</script>
```

Comment: This should be `mean`, not `median`.  They happen to be the same for this simple example, but that's unusual.

Answer (score 2):

I would write it like this, hope it helps!

```js
const stats = R.pipe(
  R.groupBy(R.prop('city')),
  R.map(
    R.applySpec({
      count: R.length,
      avg_play_time: R.pipe(
        R.map(R.path(['other', 'playtime'])),
        R.mean,
      ),
    }),
  ),  
);

const data = [
  { name: 'A', city: 1, other: { playtime: 30 } },
  { name: 'B', city: 2, other: { playtime: 20 } },
  { name: 'c', city: 1, other: { playtime: 20 } },
];

console.log('result', stats(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's pretty clean. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I like all the other answers given so far.  So naturally I want to add my own.  ;-)

Here is a version that uses `reduceBy` to keep a running track of the count and mean.  This would not work if you were looking for the median value or some other statistic, but given a count, an average, and a new value, we can calculate the new count and average directly.  This allows us to iterate the data only once at the expense of doing some arithmetic on every iteration.

```js
const transform = reduceBy(
  ({count, avg_play_time}, {other: {playtime}}) => ({
    count: count + 1,
    avg_play_time: (avg_play_time * count + playtime) / (count + 1)
  }),
  {count: 0, avg_play_time: 0},
  prop('city')
)
const someObj = [{city: 1, name: "A", other: {playtime: 30}}, {city: 2, name: "B", other: {playtime: 20}}, {city: 1, name: "c", other: {playtime: 20}}]

console.log(transform(someObj))
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script>
<script>
const {reduceBy, prop} = ramda
</script>
```

This is not point-free.  Although I'm a big fan of point-free style, I only use it when it's applicable.  I think seeking it out for its own sake is a mistake.

Note that the answer from Scott Christopher could easily be modified to use this sort of calculation

Comment: I think that is a good use-case for point-free style, please have a look at my implementation.

Comment: thanks, Scott! I agree that seeking out for a particular style is not applicable but at the same time its always good to know the variations of how to implement it. I would have use the `array reduce` method and use it without having to go the ramda route.